# Issues with Installing Inline::Java on Windows running Strawberry Perl

Tags: java, perl, inline, perl-module, cpan

I am trying to install `Inline::Java` on Windows 10 machine, running ActivePerl. since `cpan -i Inline::Java` did not work, I downloaded the module, and tried to do the installation:

```
perl MakeFile.PL
gmake
gmake test
gmake install

Welcome to the Inline::Java installation procedure.

Using C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131 as J2SDK directory.

Default J2SDK for Inline::Java will be 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131'.
See module documentation for information on how to use a different J2SDK
or change this default value.

Inline::Java can use a JNI extension that allows the Java Virtual Machine
(JVM) to be dynamically linked with Perl instead of running as a separate
process. The use of this extension is optional, and building it still
allows Inline::Java to run the JVM in the default (separate process)
fashion.
Note: You need a C compiler to build the extension.
Do you wish to build the JNI extension? [y] y

Building JNI extension.

Building with:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include\jni.h
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\include\win32\jni_md.h
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\lib\jvm.lib
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Note: In order for Inline::Java to use the JNI extension, you will need to
use the JNI configuration option or set the PERL_INLINE_JAVA_JNI environment
variable to a true value. You will also need to add the following directories
to your PATH environment variable:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server
See README.JNI for more information.

The PerlInterpreter extension allows Inline::Java to be loaded directly from
Java using an embedded Perl interpreter. It is still EXPERIMENTAL and
may not build or work properly on all platforms. See documentation for
more details.
Do you wish to build the PerlInterpreter extension? [n] n

Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Inline::Java
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

You can continue the installation with the following commands:
  % nmake
  % nmake test
  % nmake install

C:\Users\msrivastava\Downloads\Inline-Java-0.53>gmake
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation -g -d Java\classes Java\sources\org\perl\inline\java\*.java
javac: file not found: Java\sources\org\perl\inline\java*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
gmake: *** [Makefile:981: java.ts] Error 2

C:\Users\msrivastava\Downloads\Inline-Java-0.53>gmake test
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation -g -d Java\classes Java\sources\org\perl\inline\java\*.java
javac: file not found: Java\sources\org\perl\inline\java*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
gmake: *** [Makefile:981: java.ts] Error 2

C:\Users\msrivastava\Downloads\Inline-Java-0.53>gmake install
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation -g -d Java\classes Java\sources\org\perl\inline\java\*.java
javac: file not found: Java\sources\org\perl\inline\java*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
gmake: *** [Makefile:981: java.ts] Error 2
```

Has anybody faced a similar issue or successfully installed `Inline::Java` on Windows with Strawberry Perl?

Comment: It seems to interpret the backslash in `java\*.java` as an escape, not a path separator. Why do you use `gmake` when it says `nmake`?

Comment: Using / instead of \  might just do.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure worked for installation on windows 7:

1. JDK Java Development Kit version 7 is installed
2. JAVA_HOME variable is in PATH
3. install Inline, Inline::C
4. install Inline::Java 0.58 from a tar file,  not from cpan
5. from an untared folder: perl Makefile.PL J2SDK="c:\path\to\java_home" (JNI option no)
6. dmake, dmake test, dmake install

Other procedures may work too.

Comment: javac wants to write to C:\yourstrawberry\perl\site\lib\Inline\Java\sources\org\perl\inline\java\\*.java  So check if the path is writable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the source code of the Makefile & MakeFile.PL
changed path at line 8 in MakeFile.PL & changed path in MakeFile at java.ts section at line 93.
I had to insert 1 more slash where the path was given and it worked.
Also, don't run make test. directly make install.